# How to get path of selected file in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, electron

I want to when a person chooses a file,that file converts to Uint8Array Data.How can I do that?
I need something like that.

```
var selectedfile = <selected file in html> //('/tmp/file-to-be-encryped');something like that


const file = fs.readFileSync(selectedfile);

const fileForOpenpgpjs = new Uint8Array(file);
```

I need to do that in js and html only because I'm using electron and that only support Html,JS and CSS.
Thank you

Comment: `selectedFile.onchange = function(){ var files = this.files, file; if(this.files.length){ file = files[0]; var fileName = file.name; } }`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File/name

Comment: Directly out of the Electron Documentation: [Example of getting a real path from a dragged-onto-the-app file:](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/file-object)